# Change ip of browser and navigate to a link C# form App

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change the ip adress of the browser, and navigate to a link. And if I create 5 browser they must use different ip and navigate to a link.
I will add text box that will get ip and port no. and use that data to change ip.

This is not necessary to use chromium browser. Use any browser and change ip.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string link = "https://www.whoer.net";

            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);

            // Create the browser control
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("about:blank");
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Controls.Add(browser);


            // Load the website
            browser.Load(link);

        }
```

I tried diff codes but could not change ip adress

Comment: What do you mean by 'change ip'? You want the remote server see incoming calls as originating from different IP than the one of computer running your code? Is there any proxy software running on machines bearing the target IP?

Comment: A browser does not have an IP the system the browser is running on has one (or multiple). If you need 5 different ones you may create that many virtual machines and set their IPs accordingly.

Comment: You may use a network that tries to protect your identity. Tor for example and maybe use its browser. I assume the Tor network will change your IP randomly.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you want to *achieve* with this. An IP is nothing you would give to yourself. You also don't give yourself a name, instead it is given to you by your parents. In the internet that is similar to the DNS, which gives you a new IP. But that's nothing your broswer does, but instead the *maschine* where that browser is executed. So you need to reconnect that maschine to the internet.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain You presumably meant something like DHCP not DNS. DNS may give you a name for an IP or vise versa but does not assign new IPs.

Comment: @Ralf eeehm, yes, you're right. Anyway you cannot just "give yourself an IP". That pretty much contradicts the purpose of an IP, which is about identifiying who made a specific request.

Comment: We use vpn extentions to change ip of the browser for diff. purposes. I want to achive this in form app. For Example I create a browser using above code and navigate to link it will goto link using my orignal ip, but i want to change ip progrmaticly as we can in chrome using any vpn extention. If I create 5 browsers, all the browsers should use diff. ip (ip that i will provide) e.g 5 chrome browser using vpn to change ip. I hope you will get my point.

Comment: I will get IPs by Proxy providers like many website provide free or paid proxies, and provide these IPs using textbox or ListBox to Created Browsers